# AngularJS wait for all async calls inside foreach finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, trello

I am looping through an array with angular.forEach and calling a non-angular ajax library (Trello client.js). The client does have 'success' and 'error' callbacks, but doesn't return an angular deferred. I would like to execute a function once all of the ajax calls have completed.

I have the following code:

```
$scope.addCards = function(listId)
            {
                var cardTitles = $scope.quickEntryCards[listId].split('\n');
                angular.forEach(cardTitles, function(cardTitle,key)
                {
                    Trello.post('/cards', {
                        name:cardTitle,
                        idList:listId
                    },function(){ }, function(){ });
                });
                //TODO: wait for above to complete...
                $scope.init($routeParams.boardId);  
                $scope.quickEntryCards[listId] = '';    
            };
```

What can I do at that //TODO and in the callback functions so that the last 2 lines only run after all the posts either succeed or fail?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

pseudo code using angular's $q service.

```
requests = [];

forEach cardTitle
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   requests.push(deferred);
   Trello.post('/path', {}, deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);

$q.all(requests).then(function(){
    // TODO
});
```

Comment: I think this gets me in the right direction, but Trello.post doesn't return a promise. So I need hook into the callbacks they use and an angular promise...

Comment: Interesting, I see I missed that in your question. Strange because it looks like it would return a promise. You can make anything a promise though using $q.defer(). I will add pseudo code to example.

Comment: yep, that did it.  Trello's api is async, just not angular promises so it shims nicely (now that I see how to do it ;)  You can shorten a bit by just passing deferred.resolve and deferred.reject directly as Trello's success and callback methods, like this: Trello.post('/path',{},deferred.resolve,deferred.reject);

Comment: Oh, nice call! In fact I will update my answer to reflect that for others.

Comment: Hey @Daniel I have a similar issue. Could you let me know what I am doing wrong here?function getLoggedInMember() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        Trello.members.get("me", deferred.resolve);
        deferred.promise.then(function (user) {
            return user;
        });
    }

Comment: @shwetaOnStack It looks like you're trying to return synchronously from getLoggedInMember.  That won't work because Trello.get is asynchronous.  In your example "return user" returns to the "then" code, not to the caller of getLoggedInMember.   Trello.members.get("me", function(user){$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.user = user;});}); may do what you need. You would then bind to user in your template. The "right" thing I think would be a full-on Angular Trello service.

Comment: Wouldn't it hit $q.all before the push in forEach is done? Any plunkers or JSFiddles on this one?

Comment: @Omkar `q.all` sets a handler for when each deferred object in `requests` has completed. so yes, the handler is set before each request completes, but that's ok becuase we are just telling it what to do once that happens.

Comment: My bad, I assumed forEach to be non-blocking. Works like a charm :)

Comment: I believe you need to use `requests.push(deferred.promise);` for this to work. Otherwise, `$q.all(requests).then(...)` will be called right away.

Comment: You can also use `map` instead of `forEach`, returning deferred each time

Comment: @pomber I like that better

Answer (score 11):

For those looking for the answer to the question's title **"AngularJS wait for all async calls inside foreach finish"**, here is a generic way to achieve it, also using angular's $q service:

```
$scope.myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
var loopPromises = [];
angular.forEach($scope.myArray, function (myItem) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    loopPromises.push(deferred.promise);
    //sample of a long-running operation inside loop...
    setTimeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve();
        console.log('long-running operation inside forEach loop done');
    }, 2000);

});
$q.all(loopPromises).then(function () {
    console.log('forEach loop completed. Do Something after it...');
});
```

Here is a working [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/alfeugds/2pmzyh7z/).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the async library https://github.com/caolan/async.

So you can either run all your asyn functions in parallel or series and your common callback will be executed once all of them are finished.

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);

async.series([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wouldn't async's `forEach`/`forEachSeries` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Simply , you can do like this

```
var jsonArray3=[];
angular.forEach($scope.jsonArray1,function(value,key){
    angular.forEach(jsonArray2,function(v,k){
        if(v.id==value.id){
            $scope.jsonArray3.push(v);
        }
    })
})



$q.all($scope.jsonArray3).then(function(data){
   console.log("data:",data);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map`:

```
var requests = cardTitles.map(function(title) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  Trello.post('/path', {}, deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
  return deferred;
});

$q.all(requests).then(function() {

});
```

And if the `post` method already returns a promise:

```
var requests = cardTitles.map(function(title) {
  return $http.post('/path/' + title, {});
});

$q.all(requests).then(function() {

});
```